# Vue.js - data access with dynamic components

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have simple web page that shows a result list and users can switch between **table** or **li** style.

I got simple Vue with two dynamic components : *results-array* and *results-list*.

It works like a charm except when I switch from the first component to the second one: I loose results properties called in mustache (I got blank values with no error) :

```
{{contact.img_path}} does not show anything
```

whereas

```
<img :src="contact.img_path" /> works great
```

** UPDATE **
Here a simplified jsfiddle to try out: https://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/151906/

My files :

**contact.js**

```
var list = Vue.component('results-list', {
    template: '#results-list-template',
    props: ['display_mode', 'contacts']
});

var table = Vue.component('results-array', {
    template: '#results-array-template',
    props: ['display_mode', 'contacts'],
});

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router,
    data: {
        currentResultsView: 'results-array',
        display_mode:       'array',
        contacts:           [],
        contact:            { company: {}, phones: {}, section: {}, schedule_type: {}}, // Declaring Reactive Properties
        phone:              {} // Declaring Reactive Properties
        },
    created () {
      this.navigate(this.$route.query.page);
    },

    methods: {
        changeDisplay: function(event, type){
            this.currentResultsView = (type == "array") ? "results-array" : "results-list";

            this.display_mode = type;
            console.log('contacts', this.contacts[0].lastname) // WORKS !
            },
        navigate: function(page){
            var page = page > 0 ? page : 1;
            axios.get('/', {params: {page: page, fulltext_search: this.fulltext_search, sort_dir: this.sort_dir}})
                .then((response) => {
                    this.contacts = response.data.entries;
                });
        }
    }
});
```

**index.html**

```
<ul>
  <li @click="changeDisplay($event, 'hcard')" :class="{active:display_mode == 'hcard'}">Carte de visite</li>
  <li @click="changeDisplay($event, 'vcard')" :class="{active:display_mode == 'vcard'}">Vignette verticale</li>
  <li @click="changeDisplay($event, 'array')" :class="{active:display_mode == 'array'}">Tableau</li>
</ul>

<div id="app">

  <script type="text-x-template" id="results-array-template">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
      </tr>
      <tr v-for="contact in contacts">
        <td><img :src="contact.img_path" class="contact_img" /></td>
        <td>{{ contact.firstname }}</td>
        <td>{{ contact.lastname }}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </script>

  <script type="text-x-template" id="results-list-template">
    <ul>
      <li v-for="contact in contacts">
        {{contact.firstname}} <!-- **Does not show anything** -->
        <img :src="contact.img_path" /> <!-- **Works great!** -->

      </li>
    </ul>
  </script>

  <div id="results" :class="display_mode" class="clearfix">
    <keep-alive>
      <component v-bind:is="currentResultsView" :display_options="display_options" :display_mode="display_mode" :contacts="contacts" ></component>
    </keep-alive>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: is it really empty/missing, or is it present in dom and not shown in browser ?

Comment: There is nothing in DOM. But it happens only when I switch component. 
For the first one there is no problem: all data are displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to move the two template scripts outside of the #app div

Answer (score 0):

You should either remove the key `contact` from the `data` part of your Vue root instance, or use another name in the `v-for` iterator (e.g. `v-for="myContact in contacts"`)

### UPDATE

Also, you should not use `script` tags for the template - use `template` instead, because Chrome ignores non-JavaScript `script` tags.
The solution - https://codepen.io/TMCDOS/pen/gjYWNY

Comment: If I do that, I get the following error:


*Property or method "contact" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.*

Comment: Did you update the references to `contact` with `myContact` in the template ?